# What is the Object Code Format created by Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

What is the Object Code Format created by Xcode (iOS)?? Where are they stored?
Thanks.

Comment: Look in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

Comment: since I need to provide object code of the app due to GPL issue, so I want to know what is the object code for IOS app. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode produces files in the [Mach-O format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O).

Here's the documentation: [OS X ABI Mach-O File Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html). The file format is the same on iOS.

Comment: What would be the filename extension? I can't find .o .dylib in "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData", it should be .a??

Comment: If you look far enough into all the nested directories, you should find some `.o` files.  For instance, in a simulator build of a project named `iOSPDFRenderer`, I have `.o` files in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSPDFRenderer-burgnccqmymghrcmfxsmzcgwaqjs/Build/Intermediates/iOSPDFRenderer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSPDFRenderer.build/Objects-normal/i386/`. Your directory names will be different but the structure should be similar.

Comment: I searched for .o file in that path, but found nothing. Only .a files are found...

Comment: I'm not familiar with what process would produce `.a` files, but it may not be completely out of the ordinary. They might still be Mach-O files. If you run `file whatever.a` what does it say?

Comment: liblibMHD.a: current ar archive random library